# Extra comma in HashSet

Tags: java

I'm trying to split strings by capital letters, for example when the string is "SizeColorSize", the aoutput array is: {"Size", "Color", "Size"}. This works normally. Now I want to remove the duplicates from the array and that's why I am using HashSet, so that I would have ["Color", "Size"] sorted collection. Then I am printing the output in MySQL table.

But the problem is that in the output I have one extra comma : [, "Color", "Size"]. 
Any idea why is it like that?

This is the part of the code:

```
for (int j = 0; j < configPair.size(); j++) {
    r = configPair.get(j).split("(?=\\p{Lu})");
    for (int i = 0; i < r.length; i++) {
        r = new HashSet<String>(Arrays.asList(r)).toArray(new String[0]);
        r[i].trim();
        Arrays.sort(r);
        Set<String> mySet = new HashSet<String>(Arrays.asList(r));
        sqlAttributeConfig = "INSERT INTO Config_Attributes (Config_Pairs) VALUES ('"
                    + mySet + "')";
        System.out.print(r[i]);             
    }
    System.out.println();
    r = null;
    con.stmt.executeUpdate(sqlAttributeConfig);
}
```

Comment: Why are you inviting a SQL injection attack by building the SQL yourself anyway? Use a prepared statement instead.

Comment: Maybe there's an empty String in the array. Does the size of `r` equal 3 when given "SizeColorSize" as input?

Answer (score 4):

When the beginning of a `String` matches the regex pattern in `String.split()`, it results in an additional empty `String`.

So the `split` will return you ["", "Size", "Color", "Size"] instead of ["Size", "Color", "Size], thus the behavior.

The official Javadoc of Split said the following:

> The array returned by this method contains each substring of the input
>   sequence that is terminated by another subsequence that matches this
>   pattern or is terminated by the end of the input sequence.

So I guess the leading empty `String` qualifies as a "substring of the input sequence that is terminated by another subsequence that matches this pattern", as said in the doc.

Comment: I just solved it by `mySet.remove("")`. Thanks for the responses.

Comment: Well that is the behavior of split, so I cannot think of a better fix for you. Hope the answer sorts of helped:)