# Split a string in Java with blank removed

Tags: java, string, split

What I want to split is the following string:

```
<java><jquery><comments>
```

I use the following split method like this:

```
   String s = "<java><jquery><comments>";
        String[] arr = s.split("<|>");
        for(String a: arr){
            System.out.println(a);
        }
```

The output is the following:

```
java

jquery

comments
```

The problem is I don't want the blank line. The size of the array returned from splitting is 6. What I want it to be is 3 letter strings only.

Should I use regular expression to get all letters, or use split like above?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Change the split to `s.split("[<>]+")`. However, there still will be a `""` at the beginning of the array, which is due to [how split works](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16193426/extra-comma-in-hashset/16193531#16193531).

Comment: If you're using `[]` you would want to remove the `|`.  Otherwise you will split on the `|` character as well.

Comment: Thanks, missed that character. Tried to be too fast a gun in the answer:)

Answer (score 2):

I think rather than String#split you should Pattern, Matcher and Matcher#find like this:

```
Pattern p = Pattern.compile("<([^>]+)>");
Matcher m = p.matcher("<java><jquery><comments>");
for (int i=0; m.find(); i++)
    System.out.printf("MATCHED[%d]: [%s]%n", i, m.group(1));
```

#### OUTPUT:

```
MATCHED[0]: [java]
MATCHED[1]: [jquery]
MATCHED[2]: [comments]
```

Answer (score 0):

You can also use a **[StringTokenizer](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.3/docs/api/java/util/StringTokenizer.html)** object to split your string according to the correct pattern.