# String.split() returning a "" unexpectedly

Tags: java, regex, string

I have a simple method splitting a string into an array. It splits it where there are non-letter characters. The line I am using right now is as follows:

```
String[] words = str.split("[^a-zA-Z]");
```

So this should split the string where there are only alphabetical characters. But the problem is that when it splits it works for some, but not all. For example:

```
String str = "!!day--yaz!!";
String[] words = str.split("[^a-zA-Z]");
String result = "";

for (int i = 0; i < words.length; i++) {
    result += words[i] + "1 ";
}

return result;
```

I added the 1 in there to see where the split takes place, becuase i was getting errors on null values. Anyway, when I run this code I get an output of:

```
1 1 day1 1 yaz1
```

Why is it splitting between the first two !'s and after one of the -'s, but not after the last two !'s? Why is it even splitting there at all? Any help on this would be great!

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16193426/extra-comma-in-hashset/16193531#16193531

Comment: Never assume the java method is wrong.

Comment: I didn't assume it was wrong, I was just confused as to why it was happening.

Comment: Have you read the javadoc? Please tell us where you think the behaviour is not in line with the docs.

Comment: "Why is it splitting between the first two !'s and after one of the -'s, but not after the last two !'s?" because _trailing_ empty strings are discarded. Why that is, I don't know.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It doesn't split before or after it splits ON the matches, therefore you get an empty String between the dashes and the bangs.

This doesn't apply to the trailing bangs, because trailing empty Strings are omitted as described in the [javadoc](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#split%28java.lang.String%29)

> Trailing empty strings are therefore not included in the resulting
>   array.

Comment: Thank you! Solved this by adding a `+` to the end of the regex, and then adding an if statement inside the loop to check for blank spaces so it does not return them.

Answer (score 3):

This happens because it indeed uses every non-letter character as a delimiter. It means that string `"!"` will be splitted into array of 2 empty strings to the left and to the right of the exclamation sign.

Your problem can be solved withing 2 steps.

1. use `"[^a-zA-Z]+"` instead of `"[^a-zA-Z]"`. The `+` will help you to avoid empty string between 2 dashes.
2. Remove starting and trailing non-letter characters before splitting. This will remove leading and trailing empty strings: `str.replaceFirst("[^a-zA-Z]+").replaceFirst("[^a-zA-Z]+$")`

Finally your split will look like:

`String[] words = str..replaceFirst("[^a-zA-Z]+").replaceFirst("[^a-zA-Z]+$")split("[^a-zA-Z]");`

Answer (score 1):

If you want to get rid of some of the extra splits, use `split("[^a-zA-Z]+")` instead of `split("[^a-zA-Z]")`. This will match a continuous part of the `String` that matches the pattern.