# Strange behavior of Java String split() method

Tags: java, string, split

I have a method which takes a string parameter and split the string by # and after splitting it prints the length of the array along with array elements. Below is my code

```
public void StringSplitTesting(String inputString) {

        String tokenArray[] = inputString.split("#");

        System.out.println("tokenArray length is " + tokenArray.length
                + " and array elements are " + Arrays.toString(tokenArray));

    }
```

**Case I :** Now when my input is **abc#** the output is  `tokenArray length is 1 and array elements are [abc]`

**Case II :** But when my input is **#abc** the output is `tokenArray length is 2 and array elements are [, abc]`

***But I was expecting the same output for both the cases.*** What is the reason behind this implementation? Why split() method is behaving like this? Could someone give me proper explanation on this?

Comment: Everything before the first match is returned as the first element.

Comment: If you want to remove the empty string you can just call tokenArray.remove("");. But yes that is from the implementation of split.
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16193426/extra-comma-in-hashset/16193531#16193531 take a look at this post.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One aspect of the behavior of the [one-argument `split` method](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#split-java.lang.String-) can be surprising -- trailing nulls are discarded from the returned array.

> Trailing empty strings are therefore not included in the resulting array.

To get a length of `2` for each case, you can pass in a negative second argument to the [two-argument `split` method](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#split-java.lang.String-int-), which means that the length is unrestricted and no trailing empty strings are discarded.

Answer (score 2):

Just take a look in the documentation:

> Trailing empty strings are therefore not included in the resulting
>   array.

So in case 1, the output would be `{"abc", ""}` but Java cuts the trailing empty String.
If you don't want the trailing empty String to be discarded, you have to use `split("#", -1)`.

Answer (score 0):

The observed behavior is due to the inherently asymmetric nature of the **substring()** method in Java:

This is the core of the implementation of **split()**:

```
         while ((next = indexOf(ch, off)) != -1) {
            if (!limited || list.size() < limit - 1) {
                list.add(substring(off, next));
                off = next + 1;
            } else {    // last one
                //assert (list.size() == limit - 1);
                list.add(substring(off, value.length));
                off = value.length;
                break;
            }
        }
```

The key to understanding the behavior of the above code is to understand the behavior of the **substring()** method:

From the Javadocs:

> **String java.lang.String.substring(int beginIndex, int endIndex)**
>
> Returns a new string that is a substring of this string. The substring
>   begins at the specified beginIndex and extends to the character at index
>   endIndex - 1. Thus the length of the substring is endIndex-beginIndex.
>
> Examples:
>
> "hamburger".substring(4, 8) returns "urge"  (not "urger")
>
> "smiles".substring(1, 5) returns "mile"   (not "miles")

Hope this helps.